# How can i make sample json like this in php script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to make the sample php code that produce json data like this :

```
?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */
[
/* Apr 2006 */
[1145404800000,65.65],
[1145491200000,67.63],
[1145577600000,67.04],
[1145836800000,65.75],
[1145923200000,66.17],
[1146009600000,68.15],
[1146096000000,69.36],
[1146182400000,70.39],
/* May 2006 */
[1146441600000,69.60],
[1146528000000,71.62],
[1146614400000,71.14],
[1146700800000,71.13],
[1146787200000,71.89],
[1147046400000,71.89],
[1147132800000,71.03],
[1147219200000,70.60],
[1147305600000,68.15],
[1147392000000,67.70],
[1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
[1147910400000,63.18],
[1147996800000,64.51],
[1148256000000,63.38],
[1148342400000,63.15],
[1148428800000,63.34],
[1148515200000,64.33],
[1148601600000,63.55],
[1148947200000,61.22],
[1149033600000,59.77],
/* Apr 2013 */
[1364774400000,428.91],
[1364860800000,429.79],
[1364947200000,431.99],
[1365033600000,427.72],
[1365120000000,423.20],
[1365379200000,426.21],
[1365465600000,426.98],
[1365552000000,435.69],
[1365638400000,434.33],
[1365724800000,429.80],
[1365984000000,419.85],
[1366070400000,426.24]
]);
```

*edit

data like this : http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

but without load external json script into php script. simply makes json data in one script php. how can i make one like this?

Comment: Where is the data coming from, would simple print work for you, or do you need something else? If you need something else, can you be more specific?

Comment: I dont get the question either, please be more specific

Comment: the data is coming from the database, but basically i need to print this data as json... so i need the example code that produce this array in json...

Comment: I edit the question before it was downvoted, please give me reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 6):

Create a multidimensional array with the data:

```
$data=array(
array(1145404800000,65.65),
array(1145491200000,67.63),
array(1145577600000,67.04),
array(1145836800000,65.75),
array(1145923200000,66.17),
//...
);
```

Use json_encode to convert it to a json string:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: result : `[[1.1454048e+12,65.65],[1.1454912e+12,67.63],[1.1455776e+12,67.04],[1145836800000,65.75],[1.1459232e+12,66.17]]`
i'm not sure of this. but the sample json code i provide is very  human readable. how can i make code like that?

Comment: Sorry then, php converts big numbers to scientific notation. Provide these numbers as strings then: (string)1145404800000 or "1145404800000"

EDIT: Wait don't, strings will be in quotes in the result. Just a moment, and I'll check how to force keeping simple integer format.

Comment: Okay, so in my environment (PHP 5.4) it works... For me it outputs these numbers in the original format, not in scientific notation. After Googleing, I've found that this is indeed a bug in some PHP (5.2) versions: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43053

Comment: okay thanks, now i made a question again. how can i make this json data (array in array) from mysql database. can you provide dummy example? really sorry for this...

Comment: hey bro, the first at the code contain `?(` and at the end `);` how can i make this array??

Answer (score 2):

Generate your array of data however you need it, and pass it into [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: how can i made this array without array name like json code i provide?

Comment: Like you make any array in PHP. Working with arrays is one of the most basic elements of PHP programming. Consider reading the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php